# Facebook custom story with HTML

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I want to create a facebook custom story like nike does, but i'm not able to figure out how they wrote html with css actions and maybe javascript in facebook (Hover over the bars change the distance runned and change the date when you do it and some other stuff)

Any ideas will be appreciate

[image: Nike Graph on Facebook]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To achieve this you have to use Facebook graph api. there is no need to create a custom story use the common stories  and post the parameters and you will be able to see that effect. It comes by default[Faceboook takes care of it].

Comment: Could you tell me what part of the open graph handle this?

Comment: there is a fitness object in common stories, use that and with that object use either run... as an action